# Push messages when message is received in python website

Tags: python, push-notification, chat

I have made a website , and there are users in it who can send and receive messages to each other, i need to develop a mechanism in which when message is send to a user & if user is login it  shows him a message that you have received a message without refreshing the page or fetching from database if message received . just like it is working in facebook and many other sites actually i want to make a chat between 2 users.

Comment: You will need to use jQuery or dive into one of the modern Front-End Frameworks like React/VueJS/Angular. This has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: YOU need to use some framework with python in order to fulfil this

Comment: i have developed in which a user sends a message and it is added to database , it shows when receiving user reloads the page , but how can i make it like it trigger when he has got a message in database , then after trigger i can use js, or any other framework to show notification

Comment: @AadilBanaras There is not way to do this _without_ JavaScript (expect maybe [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but this I haven't touched yet). Your Django application just serves a static HTML page to the browser. There is no way for the browser to know that a new message is waiting for the user. The previously mentioned Front-End frameworks can help you to ask the backend (your Django application) whether there are new messages and update the page accordingly, without loading.

Comment: yes , i have made the solution , but using node js . it is working fine now.